# Python list[list]

Tags: python, list

I'm leetcoding the permutations problem using python which I'm not familiar with. It shows empty results by doing:

```
 ans.append(curr)
```

while it would be correct by appending curr[:].

```
ans.append(curr[:])
```

What's the problem of appending curr directly?

https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/description/

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        def backtrack(curr):
            if len(curr) == len(nums):
                ans.append(curr)
                # ans.append(curr[:])
                return
            for num in nums:
                if num not in curr:
                    curr.append(num)
                    backtrack(curr)
                    curr.pop()

        ans = []
        backtrack([])
        return ans
```

I add new list item into a list `ans.append(curr)` but got empty result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ans.append(curr)` appends the list `cur` which you later modify in the for loop.

When you do `ans.append(curr[:])` it adds a copy of the list, instead of the list itself.

Comment: I did not realize curr[:] is actually coping the list. For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment